# Alpine size and Docker Layers

Tags: docker, containers, alpine-linux

I am designing the containerization of applications at my company.  As I look at containers I see a lot of discussion around Alpine.

The basics of the discussion center around the size of Alpine.  Alpine is much smaller than other Linux distributions.  Alpine has a size of 5 MB (which is amazingly small) compared to Ubuntu which has a size of 188 MB.

But where I am getting confused is why this really matters much.  The docker layer containing the operating system should only need to download to the machine once (assuming all containers use the same base image).

For example, assume I have 50 applications that I will put in 1 container each.  They each need 50 MB, and I run each of them on docker.

- Running on Alpine, my 50 containerized applications will take up 2,505 MB of disk space.
- Running on Ubuntu the 50 applications will take 2,688 MB of disk space.

That is only a 7% difference.  Disk space is not very expensive.  So the extra 183 MB that Ubuntu takes to be able to run all the containers does not seem to really matter much.

But Alpine really has a lot of popularity.  So I have to think I am missing something.  Maybe it uses less memory?  Or it is faster?

**What features are in the Alpine Linux distribution that caused Docker to choose it as its primary container platform?**

Comment: One thing that comes to mind might be "less installed packages == less potential for security issues".

Comment: Especially if you’re building your own images yourself, Docker image layers mean the base image will generally be shared; you only pay that 183 MB difference once and not once per image.

Comment: @Marvin - That is what intended to say (I edited it to be more clear).  But as I understand layers in docker, it only downloads the Alpine layer once and then that is used for all 50 different container images.

Comment: "But where I am getting confused is why this really matters much." It doesn't, for exactly the reasons you have pointed out. Using a consistent base image is far more important than optimizing an individual image for size. Alpine is popular because it's very quick to download, and it has sufficient tooling "out of the box" to be immediately useful for testing things. It's a fine platform on which to build your images, but it's not really compelling if you're already familiar with ubuntu/fedora/whatever.

Comment: if you are using c programs, alpine uses musl c and not glibc. that doesn't make it better or worse per se, just different from ubuntu and its brethren.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the programming language you're using; for Python I feel Alpine is a bad idea:

1. No binary wheels, so you need to recompile everything, which means you need to install a compiler toolchain, thus making the smaller image somewhat moot.
2. The alternative libc Alpine uses, musl, has a history of slight differences that cause annoying bugs, e.g. one time DNS wouldn't work in Minikube at WeWork offices(!) because WeWork had wonky DNS setup at the time that interacted badly with an admittedly RFC-conformant decision musl made.

(Longer version: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/)

First issue isn't relevant for Go, and for the second issue Go mostly bypasses the libc and does syscalls directly. So for Go I think it's mostly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this is the usage that most developers have for containers. Generally as many use docker to move on a Microservices architecture the need for modularity is paramount. Thus many companies started using containers to enable them to scale their application and manage them in a distributed matter. **This means that they split them between machines as well**, it's cheaper and much more manageable.

The benefits of using a smaller image is when you want to split up those 50 processes to different containers. It's generally not a good practice for to use one docker image for multiple processes. Take a look at this [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container)

So just to sum up alpine is more popular because it's image should represent a single app thus allowing for scallability and multiple other perks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don’t see how Alpine makes being in multiple container better.  As I said in my question, the size difference is a one time benefit per node/machine. Unless you have thousands of machines, that just will not add up to anything significant.